# how to create a training dataset for image processing

Tags: image-processing, dataset, neural-network, caffe

I have a dataset of 10 jpeg high quality aerial images with txt files containing information about each vehicle's bounding box (width, height, angle, x & y axis,...). This is an example:

```
@CATEGORY:GENERAL

@IMAGE:2012-04-26-Muenchen-Tunnel_4K0G0010.JPG

#format: id type center.x center.y size.width size.height angle 

0 30 1319 2338 35 11 56.451578

1 30 1337 2350 42 14 57.817368

2 30 224 3556 61 20 136.967797
```

How should I create a database of vehicles to train in a neural network using ***Caffe***?
Should I use *photoshop* to crop each vehicle and save them one by one? or can use the txt files to create different classes of vehicles to train in the network with sth like *Matlab*?

Comment: if you have only 10 pictures you will be faster by doing this manual in photoshop, but if you want to you can use an image library to get those files

Comment: thank you for the response. there are 10 pictures but with a lot of vehicles in them. I'm talking thousands.. Do I have to separate each vehicle by its exact boundaries or just a bounding box around it would be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that many vehicles I would not do it by hand. In python you can load the image into a numpy array and then select the boxes with the data provided in files. You can handle the angles by rotating the whole array and then select the box the same way you select a 'normal' one.

If you are using a different programming language you should be able to follow this approach as well you just need to convert the jpeg into a bitmap and somehow get it into an array.

I don't know Caffe but usually it is required to capture the exact bounderies because the neural network needs boxes of the same size.